# Connect one CPT to another CPT in a wp_query loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am looking for the most efficient way to create two separate custom post types called "venues" and "offers". The role of such would be to display on a website it in the following way:

VENUE_1

- offer A
- offer B
- etc

VENUE_2

- offer C

As you see, the venues will be quite static, once added photos and descriptions will remain the same. The most dynamic thing are offers. They will vary from each other. I know I can handle that through ACF repeater in a single CPT but I don't want to use this solution due to a few technical requirements.

Is there any way that Wordpress (or Wordpress +ACF) will allow to do that? From the flow pov it will look like that:

- an editor adds venue, with descriptions, photos etc through venue CPT
- along the time an editor adds specific offers through offers CPT, selecting via e.g. dropdown to which venue it is connected

I have never used relationship fields in ACF but afaik while selecting I need to do it fully manually and select very specific offer. And as said, I want to handle later on only offers, avoiding situation when constantly I need to add manually those via venue item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably over complicating things.

You should approach it from a taxonomy point of view, meaning,
`venue` as a taxonomy, `offer` as a custom post type.

You can use `taxonomy-<my-taxonomy>.php` to create a specific template for your custom taxonomy. eg: `taxonomy-venue.php`.

You will be able to access your venue through the following permalink `example.com/venue/my-awsome-venue`

On each `venue` taxonomy pages you will a custom query to loop through each `offer` which are listed under the currently queried venue.

You should read [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) from the codex, to have a better understanding of templating.

Comment: thanks for the direction. Really appreciate that. The only question is - can taxonomy have a typical Gutenberg editor? instead of poor textfield description? And how to link two taxonomies? so if venue will be a taxonomy what If i want to have a second taxonomy for those (like "type": homes/flats/land)

Comment: As you said your venues will be pretty much static. You can build your own template taxonomy-venue.php with that in mind. Most information will then be static. You can have a looksie at taxonomy metadata if you want to include some personalized info in regards to the venue. Tho most non-static info should come from the offer as it is a post. You can't get guntenberg for metadata tho you can use tinymce, which is the old wp editor. I'm guessing if you're using ACF it should be pretty straight forward (I never used it tho, so i'm not able to advise you on ACF fields).